# Ini file parsing in java

Tags: java, ini

I'm trying to read INI file using ini4j. The format is

```
[header]
key = value
```

```java
Ini confFile = new Ini(new File(filePath));
Map<String, String> technologyMap = confFile.get("header");

for (Map.Entry<String, String> techMap : technologyMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(confFile.get("header", "\"" + techMap.getKey() +      "\"");
}
```

I'm getting `null` as my output.

If I pass the value statically I'm getting my proper output, i.e.

```
System.out.println(confFile.get("header", "value");
```

is giving the expected output.
What is the problem here to pass values dynamically?

Comment: Are you *sure* `confFile.get("header", "value")` doesn't return `null`? I'd expect `confFile.get("header", "key")` to return `value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you get `null`. There is no option in section `header` named `"key"` (notice the quotes you added).

If you just want to dump all the values in a section (though why you'd want to dump values without their keys is beyond me), do this:

```
for (String value : technologyMap.values()) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

If you actually want to print the keys too (makes more sense), so this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : technologyMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Calling `confFile.get("header", key)`, when you already have the value, is not the right way to go.

Comment: Yes the problem was with the quotes, I removed them and it worked fine.
i only needed the values of a particular key, and the key was mapped somewhere else